# Three Primary Keys relating three different tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, primary-key

I have the following tables category, Restaurant, and menu.

A restaurant can have more than one menu, and a restaurant can also have more than one category. Each menu obviously has some number of catagories, and each catagory can be a part of a number of menus.

Can I create a table that looks like this, and has 3 primary keys?

Category ID   |   Restaurant ID   |   Menu ID

1 (Appetizer)    |   1 Chile's | 2 Dinner Menu
2 (Entree) | 1 Chile's | 2 Dinner Menu
3 (Dessert) | 1Chile's | 2 Dinner Menu
1 | 67 McDonalds | 3 Lunch Menu 
1

Comment: You can create a table using three id combine as primary key, primary key (Category ID, Restaurant ID, Menu ID)

Comment: These tables will get you to what categories of offerings you can get at each restaurant, for each menu.  Do you need to express what's actually on the menu (Bloomin' Onion, Big Mac, McFlurry)?

Comment: I do and I was planning on having each food Item have a course_id column and restaurant_id column. This way when I go back to query I can find the food items for a particular course in a particular menu. Does that make sense? I guess it ends up being a many-one relationship for food_items to restaurants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make a primary key of the tuple `(category_id, restaurant_id, menu_type_id)`. Better even, make a normal, integral primary key, and add another *index* on that tuple with uniqueness constraint. It's always good to have a fast, simple primary key, but you can certainly enforce uniqueness of the triple:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX menu_index
                 ON menus (category_id, restaurant_id, menu_type_id)
```

Or you can define the index right in the table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE menus (menu_id       INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    category_id   INT,
                    restaurant_id INT,
                    menu_type_id  INT,
                    FOREIGN KEY (category_id)   REFERENCES categories(category_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants(restaurant_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (menu_type_id)  REFERENCES menu_types(menu_type_id),
                    UNIQUE INDEX  (category_id, restaurant_id, menu_type_id)
                   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: what does the FOREIGN KEY keyword mean? What exactly does it do? I have managed to query my information fine without establishing those columns as foreign key columns. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Foreign keys are central to establishing referential integrity, which is a concept at the very heart of the relational databases (and will be covered by any book on said databases). They describe a 1:n relationship.

Comment: but how would I define certain columns as foreign keys after I have already established a table?

Comment: @derek.lo: Check the manual; you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add foreign key constraints (and indices).